# Can't connect to bot due to No Auth Header

Tags: botframework

I'm using the "com.microsoft.bot:bot-integration-spring:4.6.0-preview6" and can't connect to bot due to the following response: No Auth Header. Auth is required.

I'm trying to test my bot locally with the Bot Framework Emulator connected to localhost.

It's not an own implementation, I'm just using the following example: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-java/tree/master/samples/02.echo-bot

This is the stacktrace:

```
2020-08-18 14:35:43.018  INFO 16852 --- [           main] io.viascom.malkin.MalkinApplication      : Starting MalkinApplication on DESKTOP-AHGVLFT with PID 16852 (C:\Development\repos\malkin\build\classes\java\main started by stankovic in C:\Development\repos\malkin)
2020-08-18 14:35:43.020  INFO 16852 --- [           main] io.viascom.malkin.MalkinApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-08-18 14:35:43.703  INFO 16852 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-08-18 14:35:43.711  INFO 16852 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-08-18 14:35:43.712  INFO 16852 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
2020-08-18 14:35:43.823  INFO 16852 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-08-18 14:35:43.823  INFO 16852 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 769 ms
2020-08-18 14:35:44.044  INFO 16852 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: ServletContext resource [/index.html]
2020-08-18 14:35:44.413  INFO 16852 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-08-18 14:35:44.421  INFO 16852 --- [           main] io.viascom.malkin.MalkinApplication      : Started MalkinApplication in 1.727 seconds (JVM running for 2.761)
2020-08-18 14:36:08.538  INFO 16852 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-08-18 14:36:08.538  INFO 16852 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-08-18 14:36:08.543  INFO 16852 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 5 ms
2020-08-18 14:36:08.663 ERROR 16852 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.m.b.integration.spring.BotController   : Exception handling message

java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.microsoft.bot.connector.authentication.AuthenticationException: No Auth Header. Auth is required.
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApplyNow(CompletableFuture.java:683) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApplyStage(CompletableFuture.java:658) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenApply(CompletableFuture.java:2165) ~[na:na]
    at com.microsoft.bot.connector.authentication.JwtTokenValidation.authenticateRequest(JwtTokenValidation.java:66) ~[bot-connector-4.6.0-preview6.jar:4.6.0-preview6]
    at com.microsoft.bot.builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(BotFrameworkAdapter.java:433) ~[bot-builder-4.6.0-preview6.jar:4.6.0-preview6]
    at com.microsoft.bot.integration.BotFrameworkHttpAdapter.processIncomingActivity(BotFrameworkHttpAdapter.java:72) ~[bot-integration-core-4.6.0-preview6.jar:4.6.0-preview6]
    at com.microsoft.bot.integration.spring.BotController.incoming(BotController.java:84) ~[bot-integration-spring-4.6.0-preview6.jar:4.6.0-preview6]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.microsoft.bot.connector.authentication.AuthenticationException: No Auth Header. Auth is required.
    at com.microsoft.bot.connector.authentication.JwtTokenValidation.lambda$authenticateRequest$0(JwtTokenValidation.java:75) ~[bot-connector-4.6.0-preview6.jar:4.6.0-preview6]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApplyNow(CompletableFuture.java:680) ~[na:na]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: You can read about how auth works in the Bot Framework [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication). Does your bot have an app ID and password, and have they been configured in Emulator?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Hi @KyleDelaney, thanks for your question. I'm still working on it. I just don't get it, why I need an app ID and password for testing on localhost. But yes I added one as described in your docs. I've the feeling that this can be releated to to early stage of your java sdk ... Do you have any hints if this should work with your java sdk?

Comment: Java is still in preview, so it's hard to say what will and will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading the manual carefully and doing the following steps I achieved to connect the bot with the Emulator.

**Configure the emulator for authentication**

If a bot requires authentication, displaying a login dialog, you must configure the emulator as shown below.

*Using sign-in verification code*

1. Start the emulator.
2. In the emulator, click the gear icon in the bottom left, or the Emulator Settings tab in the upper right.
3. Check the box by Use a sign-in verification code for OAuthCards.
4. Check the box by Bypass ngrok for local address
5. Click the Save button.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#configure-the-emulator-for-authentication

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPaswword yet, leave them empty before local testing. Setting them up will mean the app requires authentication.